# Will React trigger state update if new provided value is the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does React component do some checking on it's `state` once `this.setState()` is called to see if the `state` has changed. So there will be no reconciliation phase one again after `componentDidMount` was called like in the code below:

```
// in constructor
this.state = {width: 0}
...
// in componentDidMount method
this.setState(() => ({ width: 0 }))
```

or I need to do those checks manually, like:

```
const width = getViewportWidth()
if (this.state.width !== width) {
  this.setState(() => ({
    width
  }))
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, React will re-render everytime a component gets passed props or state.

You can do some checking in `shouldComponentUpdate` and then decide whether to re-render or not.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate):

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
>   behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast
>   majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called
>   for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.
>
> Currently, if shouldComponentUpdate() returns false, then componentWillUpdate(), render(), and componentDidUpdate() will not be
>   invoked.
>
> Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering when their state changes.

TLDR;
Returning false in `shouldComponentUpdate` will prevent re-rendering, except when the state actually changed.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions

Answer (score 2):

`setState` doesn't compare the previous and current state value, it just set its and a reconcilation is done again.

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5w3y16p9qp)** that simulates this behaviour

What you can do it implement the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output
>   is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
>   behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast
>   majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or
>   state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called
>   for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.
>
> Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering
>   when their state changes.

What you would do is

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
     if(this.state.width === nextState.width) {
          return false
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions

Answer (score 1):

whenever you call setstate method,the component will update and render the view